# Build opencv project fail on eclipse ubuntu

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv, ubuntu

I want build simple opencv program on eclipse on ubuntu 16.04.

I add include path file:

```
/usr/include/opencv
```

to:

```
Properties-> c/c++Build -> Settings -> GCC C++ Compiler -> Includes -> include paths(-l).
```

And add library path:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

to:

```
Properties-> c/c++Build -> Settings -> GCC C++ Linker -> Libraries -> Librav search path (-L).
```

And add:

```
opencv_core opencv_imgproc opencv_highgui
```

to Libraries(`-l`) but when I want build project this error occurred:

```
13:10:44 **** Build of configuration Debug for project Opencv ****
make all 
Building file: ../src/OpencvTest.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/usr/include/opencv -I/home/aligoglos/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/include/opencv -I/home/aligoglos/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/include/opencv2 -include/home/aligoglos/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/include/opencv/cv.h -include/home/aligoglos/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp -include/home/aligoglos/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/include/opencv/cv.hpp -include/home/aligoglos/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/include/opencv/cvaux.h -include/home/aligoglos/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/include/opencv/cvaux.hpp -include/home/aligoglos/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/include/opencv/cvwimage.h -include/home/aligoglos/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/include/opencv/cxcore.h -include/home/aligoglos/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/include/opencv/cxcore.hpp -include/home/aligoglos/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/include/opencv/cxeigen.hpp -include/home/aligoglos/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/include/opencv/cxmisc.h -include/home/aligoglos/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/include/opencv/highgui.h -include/home/aligoglos/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/include/opencv/ml.h -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/OpencvTest.d" -MT"src/OpencvTest.d" -o "src/OpencvTest.o" "../src/OpencvTest.cpp"
In file included from :0:0:
/home/aligoglos/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0/include/opencv/cv.h:66:38: fatal error: opencv2/video/tracking_c.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
src/subdir.mk:18: recipe for target 'src/OpencvTest.o' failed
make: *** [src/OpencvTest.o] Error 1

13:10:44 Build Finished (took 202ms)
```

why?

Answer (score 0):

your library include file i guess is wrong it should end with /lib , u can find the right path using this command on terminal though :

```
pkg-config opencv --libs
```

hope it will help you